# Access Modal Popup Form to Add New Record to Secondary Table Related to Primary Form Record

Tags: ms-access, vba, foreign-key-relationship, popupwindow

### Scenario:

I have two tables:

- `TableA`
- `TableB` - Has a 1 to many enforced integrity relationship based on `RequestID` (many in TableB).

I have three forms:

- **`FormA`** - Filters `TableA` records based on `RequestID` from user input, then displays the record's `TableA` fields as well as associated `TableB` records via `subFormA`.
- **`subFormA`** - Queried records from `TableB` with a `RequestID` filter on `FormA`.
- **`FormB`** - ****THIS IS THE FORM I NEED HELP WITH.**** `FormB` is modal popup window. This is simply a form that allows users to add a new record to `TableB`.

### Current Functionality:

1. When a button on `FormA` is clicked, `FormB` pops up. -- WORKING
2. When `FormB` opens, it has two combo boxes: -- WORKING

   - `RequestID` (from `TableB`) - LOCKED to prevent user editing
   - `Field1` (from `TableB`)
3. `RequestID` is automatically set to that of `FormA`. -- WORKING

### My Issue / Goal:

Issue: Although step 3 is working, my form is auto-populating with the first associated record in TableB.

Goal: Instead, I'd like the form to start on a NEW RECORD, but with `RequestID` already populated with the value from `FormA`.

### Troubleshooting:

I've tried:

**in `FormB`'s VBA:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End Sub
```

Unfortunately this resets the `RequestID` field and I lose my connection to `FormA`.

To fix that I've tried:

**in `FormB`'s VBA

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
Me!RequestID = Forms!FormA!RequestID
End Sub
```

and

**in `FormA`'s VBA

```
Private Sub open_AddMilestoneF_button_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm "FormB"
Forms![FormB].RequestID = Me.RequestID
End Sub
```

Neither of those worked. So I've also tried:

**on `FormA`'s VBA:

```
Docmd.OpenForm "FormB",,,,acFormAdd,acDialog
```

But this yields similar results (`RequestID` is reset).

Does anyone have any ideas? Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! I just removed 100% of the code related to FormB and started from scratch.

On `FormA`, I added a simple...

```
Private Sub open_FormB_button_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "FormB"
End Sub
```

Then on `FormB`, I added the following code:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
    Me.RequestID = Forms!API_BurndownPrimary_F!RequestID
End Sub
```

Boom! All done.